# "Slots" prop does nothing when applied on material-ui Slider component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui

I am trying to figure out what "slots" prop has to offer to the Slider component in terms of taking control of inner components rendering (track, thumb, etc).

I am rendering a simple Slider component as shown below

```
const marks = [
  { value: 0, label: '0' },
  { value: 10, label: '10' },
  { value: 20, label: '20' },
  { value: 30, label: '30' },
  { value: 40, label: '40' },
  { value: 50, label: '50' },
];

const SliderUsingSlots = () => (
  <Slider
    defaultValue={0}
    step={null}
    marks={marks}
    min={marks[0].value}
    max={marks[marks.length - 1].value}
    slots={{ root: 'div', thumb: 'div' }}
  />
);
```

However, not even this simple example is working for me. "Slots" prop is not being processed in any way (root and thumb spans not being changed to divs), it is just passed to the DOM

```
<span slots="[object Object]" class="MuiSlider...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the slots prop for Slider is not working (fully) in mui 5.9.3. Try to upgrade to 5.10.x.

Comment: This is great! I had 5.8.x and never thought to upgrade the minor version. You, sir, are a life saver! Thank you